# Package not created when I create new Java Project from VSCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, package

When I Create a new Project in Java, I don't get a package and when I manually create it, the Classpath changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a package in VS Code is equivalent to create a folder, then every time you create a .java file under the package folder, there will be a statement `package name;` added automatically on the top line. If not, please add it manually to avoid compilation error.

About **Classpath**, you can get it with the function `this.getClass().getResource("/").getPath()`, which is already shown in execution scripts:

[image]

After creating a package:
[image]

You can see that the Classpath was the same one and not changed.